# 'key' in dict vs. dict.get('key')

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Cuál es la diferencia principal entre:

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> existe = dic['key'] if 'key' in dic else None
>>> existe
None
```

Y:

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> existe = dic.get('key', None)
>>> existe
None
```

¿Cual es la más recomendada para comprobación de *keys* en un diccionario?

¿O tan sólo es un tema de preferencias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De cara al resultado con ambos métodos consigues lo mismo, en este caso **retornar el valor de una clave si existe en el diccionario o `None` si no existe**.

Hay que tener en cuenta que **si solo queremos comprobar si el diccionario contiene o no una clave** determinada (y no necesitamos obtener el valor asociado a ella), la forma más simple y eficiente es usar el operador de pertenencia directamente:

```
existe = key in dic
```

Donde `existe` será un boleano (`True`/`False`). En este caso se comprueba si la clave existen en la tabla hash (`__contains__`), pero no se obtiene su valor (`__getitem__`).

Volviendo al `get` vs condicional, en cuanto a cual es el preferible, aunque puede ser algo relativo lo "pythónico" es usar `dict.get`, es legible, muy compacto y con la [implementación](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d1c82c5cc7be0c21dddf86fd19c1702f6218459b/Objects/dictobject.c#L2748) actual en ***C*** del método la sobrecarga es escasa. Hay casos en los que `dict.get` es de gran ayuda, por ejemplo cuando buscamos valores en diccionarios anidados, muy típico cuando se trabaja con JSON:

```
>>> dic = {"obj1": {"foo": 4},"obj2": {"foo": 1, "bar": 3}}
>>> print(dic.get("obj2", {}).get("foo"))
1
>>> print(dic.get("obj3", {}).get("foo"))
None
```

Hay un caso en el que podríamos plantearnos usar la construcción `if-else` (o operador ternario como en este caso) por eficiencia, esto es cuando sabemos de antemano que la **gran mayoría** de las comprobaciones van a conducir al retorno del valor por defecto. En este caso concreto, en el que la clave no existe, la sobrecarga que ocasiona `get` por la llamada a función le hace perder frente al condicional, ya que en este caso todo se reduce a una comprobación de pertenencia mediante el operador `in`, un pequeño ejemplo para medir el tiempo de ejecución de ambos métodos (Python 3.6):

```
import timeit

def test1():
    dic[key] if key in dic else None

def test2():
    dic.get(key, None)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    dic = {k: 0 for k in range(10)}

    key = 5
    t_if =  timeit.timeit("test1()", number=10000000, setup="from __main__ import test1")
    t_get = timeit.timeit("test2()", number=10000000, setup="from __main__ import test2")   
    print("Clave EXISTE en el diccionario:",
          f"  Condicional: {t_if} segundos (10000000 loops).",
          f"     dict.get: {t_get} segundos (10000000 loops).",
          sep="\n",  end="\n\n"
         )


    key = 20
    t_if =  timeit.timeit("test1()", number=10000000, setup="from __main__ import test1")
    t_get = timeit.timeit("test2()", number=10000000, setup="from __main__ import test2")   
    print("Clave NO EXISTE en el diccionario:",
          f"  Condicional: {t_if} segundos (10000000 loops).",
          f"     dict.get: {t_get} segundos (10000000 loops).",
          sep="\n", end="\n\n"
         )
```

> ```
> Clave EXISTE en el diccionario:
>   Condicional: 2.186440394487514 segundos (10000000 loops).
>      dict.get: 2.118209791485714 segundos (10000000 loops).
>
> Clave NO EXISTE en el diccionario:
>   Condicional: 1.488829632557954 segundos (10000000 loops).
>      dict.get: 2.120064012042172 segundos (10000000 loops).
> ```

Se puede observar como `dict.get` es prácticamente insensible a la existencia o no de la clave en el diccionario.

> **Conclusión:** por norma general usa `dict.get`

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, esperaré a que otros también puedan responder, y si no. Tu respuesta será *la respuesta*

Answer (score 1):

```
COMPLEJIDAD:
```

Debes tener en cuenta que un diccionario es una forma de recoger datos muy rápida y sencilla, por lo que en un diccionario para saber las llaves o **keys**, el ***len*** o cualquier otra función sera de un tiempo ***O(1)*** es decir temporalidad constante, por lo que esto es mucho mas rápido que una lista cuya complejidad es ***O(n)***, en este caso tenemos:

> i in dic, dic.get()

Primero como mencione arriba todas las funciones de un diccionario es de complejidad ***O(1)*** pero esto solo ocurre en la función ***get*** pero no en si pones **in**, por que?, sencillamente **porque esto no es una función de los diccionarios**, ***get*** y otras funciones tienen una peculiar forma de funcionar internamente con una lista(un poco compleja pero rapida), entonces que sucede con ***a in dic***?, esto lo podemos asociar como un ***for i in dic*** pero esto al no ser una función de diccionarios de python y al ser un ciclo entonces simplemente recorre absolutamente todo el diccionario por lo que esto es de complejidad ***O(n)*** (líneal) lo que me quiere decir que recorre todos elementos (al igual que las listas) hasta que encuentra el objeto buscado.

> En resumen: los diccionarios son muy buenos en cuanto a consumo de memoria si manejas sus funciones correctamente, en caso contrario serán de una complejidad mayor y peor, entonces en conclusión  la función ***get*** es la ganadora.

Comment: Interesante respuesta, +1